# R to Python: Using Shift with ifelse

Tags: python, r, dataframe

Sample data:

```
test = structure(list(A = 1:16, B = c(".", NA, NA, NA, ".", NA, NA, 
NA, ".", NA, NA, NA, ".", NA, NA, NA), C = c(6L, NA, NA, NA, 
6L, NA, NA, NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA, 6L, NA, NA, NA), D = c(58, 59, 
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13), E = c(0.945252, 
0.949158, 0.945252, 0.945252, 0.945252, 0.945252, 0.945252, 0.949158, 
0.949158, 0.949158, 0.949158, 0.945252, 0.945252, 0.945252, 0.945252, 
0.945252), F = c(62.4375, NA, 62.34375, NA, 62.28125, NA, 62.28125, 
NA, 62.25, NA, 62.21875, NA, 62.25, NA, 62.28125, NA)), .Names = c("A", 
"B", "C", "D", "E", "F"), row.names = c(NA, 16L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have the above data frame in R. I wanted to replace `NA` values using some logic.

In `R` I wrote:

`test2 = test`

`library(data.table)`

```
for(m in 1:length(test2)){test2[,m] = ifelse(is.na(test2[,m]), 
                                             ifelse(is.na(shift(test2[,m]))==F, shift(test2[,m]),
                                                    ifelse(is.na(shift(test2[,m], n=2))==F, shift(test2[,m], n=2),
                                                           ifelse(is.na(shift(test2[,m], n=3))==F, shift(test2[,m], n=3),
                                                                  ifelse(is.na(shift(test2[,m], n=4))==F, shift(test2[,m], n=4),
                                                                         shift(test2[,m], n=5)))))
                                             , test2[,m])}
```

This achieved what I wanted. However now, everything I'm doing is being translated from `R` to `Python`. I have managed to translate all of my work except for this problem.

I wrote the equivalent:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

for m in range(0, len(test2.columns)):
    if test2.iloc[:,m].isnull():
        if  test2.iloc[:,m].shift(periods=1).notnull():
            test2.iloc[:,m] = test2.iloc[:,m].shift(periods=1)
        else:
            if test2.iloc[:,m].shift(periods=2).notnull():
                 test2.iloc[:,m] = test2.iloc[:,m].shift(periods=2)
            else:
                if test2.iloc[:,m].shift(periods=3).notnull():
                     test2.iloc[:,m] = test2.iloc[:,m].shift(periods=3)
                else:
                    if test2.iloc[:,m].shift(periods=4).notnull():
                         test2.iloc[:,m] = test2.iloc[:,m].shift(periods=4)
                    else:
                         test2.iloc[:,m] = test2.iloc[:,m].shift(periods=5)
```

I realise this doesn't work or even make sense in `Python` because in `R` when you use `ifelse` with `shift` it will apply the logic to each row, whereas in `Python` I believe i'm asking whether the series is `True` or `False`. For speed I don't really want to loop through the entire data frame, which is why `shift` is so great in `R`. I'm guessing there is probably an easy way to do this using `If` and `iloc` in `Python` but im a `Python` noob.

[image]

[image]

CSV:

```
 A  B   C   D   E   F
1   .   6   58  0.945252    62.4375
2           59  0.949158    
3           0   0.945252    62.34375
4           1   0.945252    
5   .   6   2   0.945252    62.28125
6           3   0.945252    
7           4   0.945252    62.28125
8           5   0.949158    
9   .   6   6   0.949158    62.25
10          7   0.949158    
11          8   0.949158    62.21875
12          9   0.945252    
13  .   6   10  0.945252    62.25
14          11  0.945252    
15          12  0.945252    62.28125
16          13  0.945252
```

Comment: your data set just triggers the batman theme in my head

Comment: Olivia, one cross-language method I've seen elsewhere is to include the CSV text, and the R and python code to read that literal text.

Comment: Pics added, CSV copied in

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`DataFrame.ffill`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html), it's a bit shorter than calling `fillna`.

```
test = test.ffill()
```

What it does is forward fills all `NaN`s with the first succeeding non-null value in each row. Alternatively, you might call `fillna` with `method='ffill'` which does the same thing:

```
test = test.fillna(method='ffill')
```

Which does the same thing as `method='pad'`.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out in python this is quite easy. Once your recognize my problem is essentially an imputation problem where I'd like to use last observation carried forward I believe it becomes as simple as:

```
test2 = test.fillna(method = 'pad')
```

Also found an easier way in `R` for the future

```
library(zoo)
test2 = na.locf(test)
```

Comment: Yes, this is one way to do it (not the shortest way though ;-) ).

Comment: Should note on a 16 mil row data frame, the `na.locf` method runs into memory issues whereas my `shift` method still works